# Rails 4:How to make users view only files in their own office

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a file tracking system whereby users can track the movement from one office to another. I've gotten most of the application to work but presently every user can view all files regardless of where it's in their office, or not because in the file index.

I am using File.all in my file index action. Is there a way I can have a user only view and track files that is only currently in their own office, while the registry officer(admin) can view and track all files?

My relationships between models:

File model

```
class Nasfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :trackers, dependent: :destroy


  before_save :file_full_number, :on => [:create, :update] 
    def file_full_number
        if self.file_sub.present?
            self.file_number = [self.file_number , self.file_sub].join('/')
        else
            self.file_number = self.file_number
        end
    end
end
```

Office Model

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department

  has_many :users
  has_many :received_files,:class_name => 'Tracker', :foreign_key => 'office_sent_to_id'
  has_many :sent_files,:class_name => 'Tracker', :foreign_key => 'office_sent_from_id'


  def self.all_without(excluded)
    where("id NOT IN (?)", excluded)
  end
end
```

Tracker Model

```
class Tracker < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :nasfile

  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :receiver, :foreign_key => :receiver_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :office_receiving, :foreign_key => :office_sent_to_id, class_name: 'Office'
  belongs_to :office_sending, :foreign_key => :office_sent_from_id, class_name: 'Office'


  before_save :office_sent_to, :on => [:create, :update] 

    def office_sent_to      
        self.office_sent_to_id = self.receiver.office.id        
    end     

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable,:recoverable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :authentication_keys => [:username], password_length: 6..25

  belongs_to :office
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :office

  has_many :sent_files,:class_name => 'Tracker', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_files,:class_name => 'Tracker', :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end

  def self.all_without(excluded)
    where("id NOT IN (?)", excluded)
  end

end
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why did you implement the `email_changed?` method? That seems like a bad idea. The `_changed?` methods are added by ActiveRecord for each column in the database, and are used to determine which columns have been changed and not yet saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing

```
@files = File.all
```

try to filter the files you include by doing something like:

```
@files = File.where("office_id = ?", current_user.office_id)
```

This way, you only get files for the office to which the user belongs.

I don't know how you have your roles set up, but you can add some branching logic to allow registry officers to see all files, regardless of office:

```
if user.role = "registry officer"
  @files = File.all
else
  @files = File.where("office_id = ?", current_user.office_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i keep getting an error "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'office_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `nasfiles`.* FROM `nasfiles` WHERE (office_id = 2)".  I think the problem is from my relationships. Do i have to add an office_id column to my files database and have it belongs to office also

Comment: Well... yes... If your design calls for a relationship between two entities, then your code would necessarily have to reflect that relationship in *some* way. You need to do a migration and amend your schema and make sure you have your has_one/has_many or belongs_to relationships reflected in your model files.

Comment: Thanks, i thought so too. I had already added the office_id to files model with a has_many relationship. I'm trying to always have the "office_id" be set to the last "tracker office_sent_to_id" using the after_save callback in the trackers model

Comment: Great to hear. Now if your original question has been answered, please click the "accept" button to let subsequent users know what worked and what might also help them. For any additional questions, please post them in their own questions.